# iOS Simulator iOS Version

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

Is there a way to detect what iOS simulator you are running.  i.e.  The difference between running 5.1 vs. 6.1.

Using [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] return x86 so i can't determine the difference between the 6.1 simulator and the 7.0 simulator.

Comment: There's one way to detect it, that's to look at the top of XCode where it tell's you what version of the simulator you're running. Or did you mean in code?

Comment: `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]` returns "6.1" on my simulator. Perhaps you mixed up `systemVersion` with `systemName` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the Availability

The relevant declarations are all in

[`Availability.h`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-18.1/Availability.h)
[`AvailabilityInternal.h`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-18.1/AvailabilityInternal.h)

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= __IPHONE_6_0
  // Here we go with iOS 6++
#else
  // This is the old way
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] should give you the information you need.  However, that is not something that should be used for logic.  It is designed to be a user-presentable string.

If you want to make logic decisions, you should do it based on capabilities.  For example, check for the existence of potentially-weak symbols at runtime before using them rather than making decisions based on the system version.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy!

Swift version:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
} else {
}
```

Objective-C version:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
} else {
}
```